# SigningConfig "release" is missing required property "keyPassword"

Tags: android, build.gradle, release

The error complains that I have not set the signingConfig.release.keyPassword, however I am setting it.

I already tried hardcoding the password instead retrieving it from the key.properties file however that didn't help.

```
// build.gradle file  

// ... the rest of the build code

android {        

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

try this: In `build.gradle(Module: app)`

```
// ... the rest of the build code

android {

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file('your_key_store_path')
            storePassword 'your_store_password'
            keyAlias = 'your_key_alias'
            keyPassword 'your_key_password'
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}
```

Also you can create `Signing Configs` in `Android Studio`:
`File` > `Project Structure` > Select `Modules` > Select `Signing Configs`.
In `Signing Configs`, there is `debug` config is already created but you can create a new one by pressing the `+` icon.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, very useful.  I'm curious, how do I do the same thing as what Android Studio does when I add a signing config, but say for example, on a CI server?  Does it temporarily populate a file somewhere for the build to pick up?

Comment: Are these details included in the exported bundle? If someone has the .apk will they be able to reverse engineer these passwords?

Answer (score 16):

In my case I used a new computer and the

```
[project]/android/key.properties
```

file was missing, because I added it to `.gitignore` and therefore it was not in the repository. It has this form: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reference-the-keystore-from-the-app

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue (in my case, the error was: **SigningConfig "release" is missing required property "storeFile"**) but the root cause was the same: I was missing the

```
[project]/android/key.properties
```

file, as pointed out by Rahul Kushwaha (Thank a lot, sir!)

What I want to share is a heads up: if you store confidential info (such as passwords) in the build.gradle, file you should add it to .gitignore, but I don´t think that´s a great idea. Therefore, as Rahul suggests, check if key.properties is missing or in the wrong location.

Answer (score 2):

Create a file named [project]/android/key.properties, that contains a reference to your keystore. Don’t include the angle brackets (< >). They indicate that the text serves as a placeholder for your values.

```
storePassword=<password-from-previous-step>
keyPassword=<password-from-previous-step>
keyAlias=upload
storeFile=<keystore-file-location>
```

Source: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android

Answer (score 1):

Check if the ***Key.properties*** file is present or not .I have pull the repo from github and this project have no ***key.properties*** file . This is the main reason for this. Now I created a new file **key.properties** and it started working.

```
storePassword=12345
keyPassword=12345
keyAlias=upload
storeFile=/Users/rahulkushwaha/Desktop/pppp/upload-keystore.jks
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue (in my case, the error was: SigningConfig "release" is missing required property "storeFile") so I resolved this by making sure below things

App-level build

build.gradle

```
release {
        if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE')) {
            storeFile file(MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE)
            storePassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD
        }
    }
```

The above property(for example MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE) matches with the below property in this file gradle.properties

In android folder

gradle.properties

```
MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE=my-upload-key.keystore
```

make sure both keys are should be matched if they mismatch then the error should be prompted

Answer (score 0):

In window try to write path as

```
C:\\Users\\<Your user folder>\\upload-keystore.jks
```

> The important note is "\" in a path.

Answer (score 0):

If you've tried every solution and you have your files where they are supposed to be, check and make sure your key.properties file is:

```
key.propterties
```

and not:

```
key.properties.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue. If you want to run the application and yet you're getting the issue, try to change the build types from left-down corner which is called "Build Variants". Just simply change the release option to debug on the "Active Build Variant" column.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLpDv.png)

It worked for me. If you are getting the same problem go Build from the main ribbon and click on Generate Singed Bundle/APK and write the keyPassword and confirm the Remember passwords checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me. I changed 'key.properties' to 'app/key.properties' in my "android/app/build.gradle" file.

This was the old code

```
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()                                 
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
```

This is the new code

```
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()                                 
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('app/key.properties')
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line

```
storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
at
android{
  release{
    storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
  }
}
```

If you have already then replace with:

```
storeFile file("key.jks") ? file("key.jks") : null
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?