# SigningConfig “release” is missing required property “storePassword”

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, build, signing

So recently I'm experiencing the following error when running `gradlew assembleRelease` on my RN App:

> SigningConfig “release” is missing required property “storePassword”.

To this date, I've already released a lot of versions of my app, but this started to happen recently in both my CI (Github) and locally.

My file `keystore.properties` is at the android root folder and configured with the proper values.

Besides that, my  `app/build.gradle` also seems to be correct:

```
    signingConfigs {
        releaseStaging {
            storeFile file(‘../keystores/liber-student-app.jks’)
            storePassword keystoreProperties[‘SIGNING_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD’]
            keyAlias keystoreProperties[‘SIGNING_KEY_ALIAS’]
            keyPassword keystoreProperties[‘SIGNING_KEY_PASSWORD’]
        }
        release {
            storeFile file(‘../keystores/liber-student-app.jks’)
            storePassword keystoreProperties[‘SIGNING_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD’]
            keyAlias keystoreProperties[‘SIGNING_KEY_ALIAS’]
            keyPassword keystoreProperties[‘SIGNING_KEY_PASSWORD’]
        }
    }
```

I also tried hardcoding the storePassword values (as suggested in this other [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57883713/7050326)), but that didn't work (exact same error)

I've stuck on this for the past 2 days, so please, help, thanks.

Comment: Did you find a resolution?