# While building APK in flutter project

Tags: flutter, gradle

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
> SigningConfig "release" is missing required property "storeFile"

Comment: have you try this  https://stackoverflow.com/q/57883438/12838877

Answer (score 2):

replace buildTypes in android/app/build. Gradle as shown as below. Alberto Azinar's answer is also correct, but if you haven't upload-keystore.it will be useful.

```
buildTypes {
   release {
       // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
       // Signing with the debug keys for now,
       // so `flutter run --release` works.
       signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
   }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue when I was working on a github project, and it was because I was trying to generate a *signed apk* without the `upload-keystore.jks` in the `android/app/` directory. Also I didn't have the `key.properties` file in the `android/` directory. I solved the issue after asking for the files and setting them in the directories mentioned above.

If you are the owner of the project maybe you should try to follow this steps from the [documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
android {
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file('your_key_store_path')
            storePassword 'your_store_password'
            keyAlias = 'your_key_alias'
            keyPassword 'your_key_password'
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}
```