# SigningConfig "release" is missing required property "storeFile" flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I try to build apk for my flutter project but this error occurred

> SigningConfig "release" is missing required property "storeFile".

this is my build.gradle signingconfigs

```
signingConfigs {
    if (System.getenv("ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PATH")) {
        release {
            storeFile file(System.getenv("ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PATH"))
            keyAlias System.getenv("ANDROID_KEYSTORE_ALIAS")
            keyPassword System.getenv("ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PRIVATE_KEY_PASSWORD")
            storePassword System.getenv("ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD")
        }
    } else {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside if condition, it's not able to find value for storeFile. Can you try adding a fallback for that property just like you did in else condition.

```
signingConfigs {
    if (System.getenv("ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PATH")) {
        release {
            storeFile System.getenv("ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PATH") ? file(System.getenv("ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PATH")) : null // this line
            keyAlias System.getenv("ANDROID_KEYSTORE_ALIAS")
            keyPassword System.getenv("ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PRIVATE_KEY_PASSWORD")
            storePassword System.getenv("ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD")
        }
    } else {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
}
```

Either the environment variable ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PATH is missing, or that value is not present in your keystore.

Check this our for similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57883438/signingconfig-release-is-missing-required-property-keypassword)