Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.


A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
SigningConfig "release" is missing required property "storeFile".


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 27s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           28.7s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
Process finished with exit code 1
it didn't work with flutter clean , flutter pub get
it happens when i try to build APK file

What does your android/app/build.gradle looks like? Especially the defaultConfig block, buildTypes block and signingConfigs block if you have that

This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57883438/8144311

Problem:
This error occurs when the release build configuration lacks the storeFile property in the SigningConfig. This property is essential for signing the APK during the build process.
Solution:
Step 1: Locate the build.gradle File
Open your project in Android Studio or your preferred IDE.
Go to the android/app directory.
Open the build.gradle file.
Step 2: Add or Update the SigningConfig for Release
Ensure you have a signingConfigs block in your build.gradle file:
android {
signingConfigs {
    release {
        keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
        keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
        storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
        storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
    }
}

}
Step 3: Create or Update the key.properties File
In the android directory, create a key.properties file (if it doesn’t exist).
Add the following:
storePassword=your_store_password
keyPassword=your_key_password
keyAlias=your_key_alias
storeFile=path_to_your_keystore_file

Step 4: Load the key.properties File in build.gradle
Ensure your build.gradle file loads the key.properties file:
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
   keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
   }

Step 5: Reference the SigningConfig in the Build Types
Make sure the release build type references the signingConfig:
buildTypes {
release {
    signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    minifyEnabled false // or true based on your needs
    // Add other configurations here
}

}
Step 6: Rebuild the Project
Run flutter clean.
Run flutter pub get.
Build your APK again with:flutter build apk --release

Note: If you don’t have a keystore, generate one with:
keytool -genkey -v -keystore your_keystore_name.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias your_key_alias

